# Getting a JSON object returned in Java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get a JSON object displayed via an API, but I get a error message along with it.

Here is the method that I've written:

```
public MarketDataListLevel1 getMarketDataTicker() {
    try {
        MarketDataListLevel1 md = CS.getMarketDataTicker();
        log.info(md.toString());
        return md;
     }
     catch ( Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     }
}
```

Where CS is an object that processes the JSON data from a URL..

For some reason, when I call that method, I'm getting the precise output that I want, but I also get these additional error messages that follow it, and I'm unsure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
14:52:55.265 [default] [main] ERROR si.mazi.rescu.JSONUtils - Error unmarshalling from 
json: {"Bid":{"Price":183.25,"Size":0.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},"Ask":{"Price":185.0,"Size":0.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},"Last":{"Price":182.44,"Size":4.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0}} 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem getting JSON object
at (Skipped all these logs)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize      instance of com.xeiam.xchange.cs.dto.MarketData[] out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5069bb01; line: 1, column: 2]
```

This is the format of the data what I want returned:

```
{"Bid":{"Price":204.08,"Size":1.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},
 "Ask":{"Price":203.2,"Size":0.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},
 "Last":{"Price":204.64,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0}}
```

And it seems to be fulfilling that.

MarketDataLevel1 is defined as:

```
public class MarketDataListLevel1 {
public MarketData[] MarketDataListLast;
public MarketData[] MarketDataListBid;
public MarketData[] MarketDataListAsk;
public MarketDataListLevel1(@JsonProperty("Bid") MarketData[] MarketDataListBid,@JsonProperty("Ask") MarketData[] MarketDataListAsk,@JsonProperty("Last") MarketData[] MarketDataListLast) {
    this.MarketDataListBid = MarketDataListBid;
    this.MarketDataListAsk = MarketDataListAsk;
    this.MarketDataListLast = MarketDataListLast;
}
```

And MarketData as

```
public class MarketData {
public BigDecimal Price;                    
public BigDecimal Size;                 
public String ExchangeID;                  
public long timeStamp;

public MarketData(
        @JsonProperty("Price") BigDecimal Price,
        @JsonProperty("Size") BigDecimal Size,
        @JsonProperty("ExchangeID") String ExchangeID,
        @JsonProperty("timeStamp") long timeStamp)          {

    this.Price = Price;
    this.Size = Size;
    this.ExchangeID = ExchangeID;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}
```

}

Comment: post the code that generates the error

Comment: How is `MarketData` defined?

Comment: Your JSON is an object, not an array. You will not get `MarketData[]` out of it, whatever `MarketData` is.

Comment: The JSON is fine.  There's something wrong with how you're accessing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my MarketDataLevel1 class is not formatted correctly, and I'm not sure ATM how to fix that.

Comment: Your JSON is an oject of objects. That can't be mapped to an object of lists of strings.

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix it from your hint, Lutz.